# American English pronunciation of 't' after 'n'

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

As a native British English speaker I often notice what seems to be an omission of the "t" sound by American speakers when the letter follows an "n".

Examples:

Interview ---> Innerview

Internet ---> Innernet

**Questions**

Do U.S. speakers hear it the same way as I do or am I missing a very subtle sound?

Does this pronunciation vary a lot across the States?

Is there an obvious explanation?

Comment: you will "often" hear "offen" as well

Comment: @user662852 - A lot of British English people say that, not just those from the US.

Comment: Related: *[Why are expressions like “gonna”, “wanna” and “shoulda” American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/394563/)*, *[AmE Phonetics: < I don't n-> /aʊn/](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/141970)* and *[“nt” pronounced as “n” in American English (as in “Internet”): what is it called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110741)*

Comment: Related: [The elision of alveolar plosives](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/237013/216106)

Comment: @chasly from UK: Agreed. But in this general area, I think Americans are more likely than Brits to articulate a /t/ (often, just as a glottal stop) at the end of, say, ***second*** in contexts such as *I'll be there in a second!* or *There is a second alternative*.

Comment: Very commonly, you would be missing a sound; or rather, _over-hearing_ one. Intervocalic /nt/ usually gets reduced in AmE to a nasalised tap, [ɾ̃]. This is quite similar to an actual [n], but the contact between the tongue and the alveolar ridge is faster and covers a smaller part of the blade of the tongue. It’s by no means unheard of for intervocalic /n/ to be reduced to a tap as well, nor for /nt/ to be realised as an actual [n], but many (I would guess most, but not sure) Americans do pronounce _interview_ and _inner view_ differently.

Comment: In AmE, non-initial 't' tends to be unaspirated, (in contrast to BrE). So it lenites pretty quickly. 'water' is almost 'wa:r'. So 'nt' goes similarly.

Comment: @user662852 The standard pronunciation of 'often', for a few hundred years, has been /'aw fɪn/ ([hear a number of these pronunciations](https://forvo.com/word/often/#en) ). With higher literacy, a number of people give a spelling pronunciation now, so [dictionaries give the 't' pronunciation as a second possibility](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/often).

Comment: This is regional. In my experience, it corresponds roughly to the Great Lakes area—I first became aware of it when a friend from Ohio noted it (I'm from Michigan, but we were both living in California at the time). He had it more strongly than me, but I do it, too. In extreme cases, "interesting" can become "innersting".

Comment: @user662852 [*Often* is **supposed** to have a silent t, not a pronounced one.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/212203/2085)

Answer (score 1):

The sound is actually realised as an alveolar flap [ɾ] rather than not pronounced at all, so Americans would consider the sounds produced by the words *inner* [ˈɪnəɹ̠] and "inter" from the word *internet* [ˈɪɾ̃əɹ̠ˌnɛt] to be two different ones. You can see the same process in words without the "nt" letters: *butter* [ˈbʌɾəɹ̠], *party* [ˈpɑɹ̠ɾi], *loader* [ˈloʊɾəɹ̠], etc.

The phenomenon is called flapping, and there is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) that thoroughly addresses this topic. Apart from the feature being prevalent in southern American accents, it's usually a choice among other Americans regardless of location from what I've experienced.

Comment: In the process of replacing the [t]'s with [ɾ]'s, I guess I forgot to scrutinise the producibility of the [nɾ] sound which is actually realised as a nasal flap [ɾ̃]. The main point is that it is definitely distinguishable from the sound produced from the word "inner". I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: You're using [r] in your transcription, but that’s a full, [multiply-tapped/trilled rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_trills), a sound virtually unheard in Englishes outside of Scotland and certainly [entirely absent in all dialects of American English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_/r/). You will want to use sounds like [ɚ] for  [ˈbʌɾɚ] or [ˈɪnɚ] or [ˈlo(ʊ)ɾɚ], [ɑ˞] for [ˈpɑ˞ɾi], and [ɻ] for words like *ruler* [ˈɻulɚ].

Comment: Fair enough. I've read that the the /r/ phoneme is conventionally transcribed as such even though it's commonly realised as an post-alveolar approximant, but for the sake of correctness, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

As an American I can tell you that in some cases the *t* isn't pronounced.  one case is that it's simply a slang way of saying those words. another case is that it can happen when a person is speaking more quickly. Speaking quickly can make words roll off the tongue more smoothly. *t* is not a very smooth sound, so it gets smoothed out. This can happen anywhere in the United States.

Comment: Thanks  - for some reason it doesn't happen this way in British English. It doesn't matter how fast we speak or how educated we are, we still pronounce it fully. The only exception would be the Cockney-type change from a 't' to a glottal stop although that happens elsewhere as well, not just after 'n'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange seeks to provide *definitive* answers; please [edit] your post to include appropriate support— for example, can you provide examples of words where this phenomenon occurs and where it does not? On a similar note, please be careful with terminology— *slang* applies to vocabulary and diction/register, not phonemics — and use standard orthography for the benefit of future visitors. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.