# Super reduced pronunciation of the affix "anti"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, flapping

Listen to [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRP6Ry7GAYk&ab_channel=AskaPharmacistbyWalgreens) at 00:13 and 00:30, and you will hear the word *antihistamine*. The pronunciation of *anti* is super reduced, just like [this post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pronunciation-anti-as-prefix.3239365/post-16396751) described. I think the IPA should be like this: /anə/. The letter T has been silenced in the word.

Have you ever heard this pronunciation in America? What's the cause of it?

Comment: 1) UK/ˌæn.tiˈhɪs.tə.mɪn//ˌæn.tiˈhɪs.tə.miːn/
2)  US/ˌæn.t̬iˈhɪs.tə.mɪn//ˌæn.t̬iˈhɪs.tə.miːn/ - From Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: The short vowel /ɪ/ is the default in some anti- words eg [antithesis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antithesis), antipodes, antimony (note that it's not always a clear difference between /ɪ/ and /ə/). And a /t/ after an /n/ is often reduced especially in the US: [see this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483665/american-english-pronunciation-of-t-after-n). So there doesn't seem anything too surprising here: the cause is people speaking casually or fast.

Comment: @StuartF But it would be mind boggling if it happened in most of the words in your example. Try it in *antithesis*, for example! That would be impossible in English. (Thus, the rationale isn't sufficient to explain why it can happen in OP's example).

Comment: @Gio It depends which Cambridge dictionary you look in. If it was as that description says, then we wouldn't really expect that pronunciation. See [this transcription](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antihistamine#), also from Cambridge, which seems more plausible (the /nt/ cluster is within the same syllable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of [flapping (see Wiki).](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) In American English, in certain positions /t/ and /d/ can get replaced with the voiced alveolar flap sound [ɾ], and (as here) /nt/ can get replaced with the nasalized flap [ɾ̃], which can also be a realization of /n/. This can create interesting sets of homophones: for some American speakers, *winner* and *winter* sound exactly alike.

This generally occurs at the end of a stressed syllable when it is followed by an unstressed one, so it applies to *antihistamine* but not to *antithesis.* The rules are a bit more complicated than that, particularly when flapping occurs on word boundaries; that Wiki page goes into some more detail.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I know the basic rule--that it happens after a stressed syllable and before an unstressed one. That allows it in *antihistamine* but disallows it in *antithesis.* But I have a feeling you'll tell me that the *actual* rule is a thousand times more complicated.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. There's secondary stress on the first syllable, and no stress on the second one; I assume that explains it?

Comment: (I did edit my answer to include that information, by the way!)